# Java regex for date and military time is failing

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to build a Java regex that supports date times (where the time component is military time):

> MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss

```
@Test
public void testRegexPattern() {
    String regex = "([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}\\s^([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d):?([0-5]\\d)$)";

    String supposedDateTime = "12/31/1969 19:00:00";

    Assert.assertTrue(supposedDateTime.matches(regex));
}
```

This test is failing because the `supposedDateTime` doesn't match the regex. Can any regex maestros out there spot why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you having `caret(^)` in the middle after `\\s`? Remove it. That is what creating the problem. Also, with `String#matches` method, you don't even need to use `anchors`.

So, you can use this regex:

```
"([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}\\s([01]\\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d):?([0-5]\\d))"
```

---

Having talked about the actual issue in regex, you should really not test dates with regex. Rather use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with appropriate pattern to `parse` the date string.